# I can't figure out why any I'm getting the following error even I am passing a value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
regionsData: RegionData[]=[];//this array has the properties as id and name

  findRegion(regionId: string) {
    console.log(regionId)
    this.regionsData.find(x => {
      console.log(x)
      
        if (x.location.id === regionId) {//----------Here at this point I'm getting the error as 
//ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') which is the above line
          this.region.location.id = x.location.id;
          this.region.location.name = x.location.name;
          console.log(this.region, x)
        }
        
    })
  }
  
  region: RegionData={
    location: {
      id: '',
      name: ''
    }
  }
  edit(regionId: string) {
    console.log(regionId, this.regionsData)
    this.findRegion(regionId)//----calling the find method here from top
    console.log(this.region)
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewRegionComponent, {
      data: {
        isUpdate: true,
        id:regionId,
        name:this.region.location.name
        // regionData: this.region.location
      }
    })

  }
```

I tried alot to find the reason to the following undefined problem but I'm failed to identity it.
Help me out to get rid of it
I tried

```
if(x.location.id!==undefined){...}
```

But Still I didn't got it and on the console its pointing error at the html part which is totally fine

Answer (score 0):

For some element in the `regionsData` array, the location field is not present, hence you are getting this error. Check if location exists or not before accessing id on it. Replace the if condition with following

```
if (x?.location?.id === regionId)
```

Comment: I will look in it and let you know